# How much overlap should bypass doors have?

Tags: doors, closet

I want to hang bypass doors in the closets. The finished opening is 48". Do I use 2 24" doors and leave gap on each end or do I use a 24 and a 26 for the overlap so they look even, or 2 26ers

Comment: Wouldn't two 24.5" doors give only a .5" overlap? You would need each door to be 25" to have them overlap 1"

Comment: Two 25" doors with no overlap would be 50" wide, so you have to overlap 2" to fit in a 48" opening.

Answer (score 4):

You want the doors to overlap a bit. You also want the two doors to be the same width so when they are slid all the way to one side or the other that they are even.

A one inch overlap is about ideal so for a 48" finished opening each door would be 24.5 inches wide.

Two 24" doors would not overlap at all and would not stay fully engaged into the center guide on the floor.

Doors wider than 24.5" would work just fine but you loose access width when the doors are open.

My suggestion is that you may want to look at bi-fold doors. These would take four ~12" wide door panels. They work with one track at the top and eliminate the center guide on the floor. When open you get much much easier access to the closet than with bypass doors. Plus when closed the whole surface is flat. The only time I consider bypass doors is when mirrored doors are used to give a smaller room a more expansive look.

Comment: I agree with that recommendation. The only thing I would also recommend is get a good set of bi-fold doors. There are many times I have seen them fail to work properly over the long haul, not on my installs, but in homes that came with them. Many complaints arising from that failure. These are doors I typically do not recommend, but it is good for your situation, given you go with quality hardware

Comment: @Jack - Yes, quality can make a huge difference in bi-fold doors. Low cost doors, particularly some models with louvered panels that are only 3/4" thick can be flimsy and lead to less than optimal operation. If they are made of wood with good sturdy hollow core construction with multi-ply face materials these doors at 1 3/8" thick (like a quality interior door) can stay working and last a long time.